# Bash Pattern Matching with rm command

Tags: bash

I have a directory that I need to remove all the subdirectories that contain a space and a number in the directory name. How would I pattern match for the given parameters? I need to do this with one rm command.
Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: not possible with one `rm` command

Comment: @Babyy, eh? Certainly it's possible.

Answer (score 7):

Just include two patterns in the same `rm` command:

```
rm -rf -- \
  *" "*[0-9]*/ \   # this one gets directories with spaces before numbers...
  *[0-9]*" "*/     # ...and this one gets directories with numbers before spaces.
```

---

If only one of the two classes exists, then the class that doesn't exist doesn't get expanded (unless the `nullglob` shell option is enabled). That's harmless, though, since `rm -f` ignores arguments that don't exist. So, let's say you had a file `foo 5`, but no files with spaces following the numbers. When you run this, the shell would do the following:

```
rm -rf -- "foo 5" "*[0-9]* */"
```

...which is harmless with `rm`, but might cause some trouble for a non-`rm` program that requires all arguments it's passed to exist.

To work around that, enable the `nullglob` option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

...and then any non-matching patterns will simply be deleted.

---

Another interesting case is when you want to avoid *duplicate* names. For instance, `client 15 jenkins` matches both `*" "*[0-9]*` and `*[0-9]*" "*`, so if you put both patterns on a single line, you get that file listed twice. You can avoid this using bash extglobs:

```
shopt -s extglob # turn on extended globbing
rm -rf -- *@([0-9]*" "|" "*[0-9])*/ # ...and now this will only emit one result
```

Comment: Won't this also get files?  OP asked for only directories.

Comment: Including only directories is why it has a trailing `/` on the patterns. You're right that I left that off the final extglob example; now fixed.

Comment: what is `@`in this command `rm -rf -- *@([0-9]*" "|" "*[0-9])*` ?

Comment: @Babyy, see the extglob section in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob. `@(foo|bar)` matches either `foo` or `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

In some circumstances you can remove all subdirs that have a number and space in the name with the following command:

```
$ ls -l tmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jun 27 19:28 a1 this.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jun 27 19:28 b2 that.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jun 27 19:28 c3 other.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jun 27 19:30 somefilenotmatched.txt

$ rm -r tmp/*[[:digit:]]*\ *

# ls -l tmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jun 27 19:30 somefilenotmatched.txt
```

You do need to know in advance the orientation of the spaces and numbers. Otherwise, two commands are required.

And, as indicated by Charles, you can avoid the character classification using `[[:digit:]]` by using the pattern `[0-9]`.

Comment: This requires the space to be after the digit. Is that ordering constraint intended? Also, why force names to contain a `.`?

Comment: I disagree, by the way, that it's necessary to know the ordering -- see my answer for two different ways to solve that (one with extglobs, the other with multiple independent patterns).

Comment: Yes, I am reading it. It is always wise to snatch pebbles from a knowing hand :-). Thanks for your many contributions.

Comment: BTW, the `[[:digit:]]` class you're using is actually better practice than `[0-9]`; I was just being lazy.

Comment: I thought character classes like [[:digit:]] were actually less efficient than [0-9], but I cannot recall why at the moment.

Comment: In both cases, locale and collation order come into play. Not a big deal for `[0-9]`, but for, say, `[A-Z]` vs `[[:upper:]]`, the former can give outright inaccurate results if used in a locale where ordering is `AaBbCc...`, and such locales do exist.